# kindle fire entre key missing

Tags: android, kindle-fire

When I tap on my edit text, soft key-board opens up but could not find any return (enter) key on it.
A simple solution is to add

```
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

so that eventually it has to show a return (enter) key.

Is it a bug?
How to get return key visible without doing something like this?

Comment: Are you trying to get an "Enter" to finish your entry, or to be done? If the latter, try IME_ACTION_DONE or IME_ACTION_GO.

Comment: A lot of keyboards place an action button where the enter key goes if the ime has an action mode or action text.  This is how android does things like putting up magnifying glasses on the keyboard for search.